# CakePHP 3: Different login redirection depending on user roles

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm using CakePHP 3 and trying to change the default route after user is logged in. I want to set default route different depends on user's `role_id`.

I found a [solution](http://www.syahzul.com/2012/11/12/change-cakephp-2-x-default-routing-after-login/) but it's only for CakePHP 2. 
I can't use it in CakePHP 3, I can't use Session component in bootstrap.

So I tried this in my AppController

```
public $redirects = [
    'admin' => ['controller' => 'Clients', 'action' => 'statistics'],
    'user' => ['controller' => 'Clients', 'action' => 'index'],
];
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    ...
    if ($this->Auth->user()) 
        Configure::write('Route.default', $this->redirects[$this->Auth->user('role_id')]);
    else
        Configure::write('Route.default', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    Router::scope('/', function($routes) {
        $routes->connect('/', Configure::read('Route.default'));
        $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
    });
}
```

My default route is

```
$routes->connect('/', \Cake\Core\Configure::read('Route.default'));
```

And I defined `Route.default` in bootstrap.php as

```
Configure::write('Route.default', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
```

But when I open the `/` page I still see the `users/login` page even if I have already logged in

So I added the redirection before `Router::scope`

```
if (
    $this->Auth->user() 
    && $this->request->params['controller'] == 'Users' 
    && $this->request->params['action'] == 'login'
) {
    $this->redirect(Configure::read('Route.default'));
}
```

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Why are you doing that anyways? When a non-logged in user would access a protected action, a redirect would happen automatically (given that the auth component is configured that way), and for logged in users it would not, so that sounds like exactly what you are trying to do here?

Comment: @ndm, thanks for your answer but I want to have different "root" page for different roles, when user with role_id = 'admin' opens my website like "example.com" he sees "clients/statistics", when user with role_id = 'user' opens the website he sees "clients/index". Different homepages for different roles.

Comment: I see, you may want to add that to your question, as it's a relevant factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hey i found a solution!

create an file in App\Routing\Filter like that:

```
  <?php
namespace App\Routing\Filter;

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Routing\DispatcherFilter;

class HFilter extends DispatcherFilter {

    public function beforeDispatch(Event $event) {
        $request = $event->data['request'];
        if (isset($request->url) && $request->url == '') {
            if ($request->session()->read('Auth.User')){
                $request->params['controller'] = 'Users';
                $request->params['action'] = 'index';
            } else { 
                $request->params['controller'] = 'Pages';
                $request->params['action'] = 'home';
            } 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

after add it into the bootstrap.php file without the Filter in the name like that

```
DispatcherFactory::add('H');
DispatcherFactory::add('Asset');
DispatcherFactory::add('Routing');
DispatcherFactory::add('ControllerFactory');
```

Comment: I changed code and now it works perfect!
`$request->params['action'] = 'display';`
`$request->params['pass'][0] = 'home';`

Comment: Note from https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/dispatch-filters.html :
<<As of 3.3.0 Dispatcher Filters are deprecated. You should use Middleware instead now.>>

Answer (score 5):

We can check user role from session data and make redirect according the role.

We can edit in the users controllers login function as follows

```
public function login()
{


    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);


            $loggedUser = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');
            if($loggedUser['role'] == 'customer'){
                return $this->redirect('/');
            }else if($loggedUser['role'] == 'admin'){
                return $this->redirect('/admin');
            }else{
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }


        }

    }
}
```

My cakephp version is 3.3.8

Comment: I want to have different pages for different roles when they visit '/' route. This only makes them redirect to the page after login.